# What is Rhino in JDK useful for?

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

`Rhino` is a `JavaScript` interpreter running on top of JVM. I guess it was useful for server-side programming in `JavaScript`. Now we have `Node.js`. So I wonder if `Rhino` is still relevant and what it is useful for.

Comment: I have used it to give users a way to add simple scripts to an application ...

Answer (score 5):

It simply provides a means to run Javascript in the JVM. As such it gives you [another implementation choice on top of the JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) in preference to the Java language (in a similar fashion to JRuby, Scala, Groovy etc.). You can write complete solutions in Javascript, or mix/match with Java (or any other JVM language)

Note that this isn't specific to 'server-side' or any such deployment choice.

Speaking from personal experience, I've used it to provide [trivial scripting in Ant deployments](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html), and to provide an out-of-the-box simple scripting language for customers using Java applications/toolsets I've written.

Answer (score 2):

Rhino is also used by the [the HttpUnit library](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/), which can be used in unit tests to emulate a web browser, for testing web sites.  It gives the library JavaScript support.

Answer (score 1):

I use Javascript with Rhino as a scripting language for my MMORPG server written in Java. It allows me to implement NPC scripts, item use scripts, event triggers and other server-sided interactive functionality in Javascript without having to touch the Java part of my server.

Implementing these features in Javascript makes the syntax for them much easier to write and read. Especially because I let the Java part of the server automatically add any trivial boilerplate code to the script sourcecode before sending them to the script engine. This further simplifies the javascript syntax.

It also allows a much clearer separation of the engine and the content.

I also added a Javascript admin shell, which allows me to run any Javascript code on the running server. This has proven to be a very useful testing and debugging tool and I expect it to be a very powerful administration tool later.

I could, of course, also have used any other scripting language, like for example Lua which is frequently used as a scripting language in game development. But Rhino is supported out-of-the-box so I don't need any additional 3rd party dependencies. Also, my client is a HTML5/Javascript application, so I don't have yet another programming language in the project. Note that although both the client and the server content use JS, there is no code shared between them - they are literally on the opposite ends of the system architecture and interact with each other through several layers of indirection, so there is no reason to share code.